# How can I view compound unique constraints/indexes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

A compound index was created on a table with this command:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX example_index 
    ON example_table (column1, column2, column3) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF);
```

How can I view the index and its specific columns using SQL statements after it's been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *little* tricky so here's an example:

```
select schema_name(t.schema_id) schema_name,
       t.name table_name,
       i.name index_name,
       i.is_unique,
       i.is_primary_key,
       c.name column_name,
       ic.key_ordinal      
from sys.tables t
join sys.indexes i
  on t.object_id = i.object_id
join sys.index_columns ic
  on ic.object_id = i.object_id
 and ic.index_id = i.index_id
join sys.columns c
 on ic.object_id = c.object_id
and ic.column_id = c.column_id
where ic.is_included_column = 0
  and t.type = 'U'
order by t.name, i.name, ic.key_ordinal
```

Answer (score 0):

As with all SQL objects, you can SELECT from the system tables and/or schema views.

Comment: I have searched the `sys.objects` table and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` table (or view?), and haven't found it.

Comment: Did you try sys.index_columns?   You may have to JOIN to sys.indexes to see everything you want.